# View Variable in Controller becomes normal variable in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I would like to know how does

**$this->view->foo**  from controller becomes **$this->foo** in view file i.e. in .phtml file

I would like to know how zend framework handled this.

Answer (score 0):

It's all handled by magic methods [`__get`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf1/blob/master/library/Zend/View/Abstract.php#L267) and [`__set`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf1/blob/master/library/Zend/View/Abstract.php#L305) in `Zend/View/Abstract.php`.

In short: do not do that in your own project, just use a similar process to ZF2/3 where parameters are passed into the constructor :)